# Error when I try to convert from imperial units to metric, the other way around works with similar code?

Tags: python

Im a noob in python3. My problem is with the following code:
It says "none m" for example when i try to convert from ft to m. every other conversion works okay.

I tried solving it with a dictionary as it is with the metric to metric conversion, but i could not because then i would not get a correct result with imperial to imperial conversions.

```
# def distance_converterv2():
metric = ["km", "m", "dm", "cm", "mm"]
imperial = ["ft", "in", "mi"]


def convert_v2(val, unit_in, unit_out):
    final = 0.0
    m = 0.0
    si = {'mm': 0.001, 'cm': 0.01, 'dm': 0.1, 'm': 1.0, 'km': 1000.0}
    if (unit_in and unit_out) in metric:
        final = val*(si[unit_in]/si[unit_out])

    if unit_in and unit_out in imperial:
        if unit_in in ['ft'] and unit_out in ['in']:
            final = val * 12

        if unit_in in ['in'] and unit_out in ['ft']:
            final = val / 12

        if unit_in in ['ft'] and unit_out in ['mi']:
            final = val / 5280

        if unit_in in ['mi'] and unit_out in ['ft']:
            final = val * 5280

    if unit_in in metric and unit_out in imperial:
        if unit_out in ['ft']:
            m = val*3.28084

        if unit_out in ['in']:
            m = val*39.37008

        if unit_out in ['mi']:
            m = val/1609.34

        final = m * si[unit_in]

    if unit_in in imperial and unit_out in metric:
        si = {'mm': 0.001, 'cm': 0.01, 'dm': 0.1, 'm': 1.0, 'km': 1000.0}
        if unit_in in ['ft']:
            m = val / 3.28084

        if unit_in in ['in']:
            m = val / 39.37008

        if unit_in in ['mi']:
            m = val * 1609.34

        final = m / si[unit_out]

    return final


def isfloat(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


print("""
Welcome to Saguaro's unit converter!

First, enter the unit you want to convert from, then the unit you want to convert to
The options are: 
    mm, cm, dm, m, km
    ft, inch, mile

Whenever You want to go back press B and enter
""")

value = 0
unit_in = ""
unit_out = ""


while True:

    unit_in = input("Unit you want to convert from: ")

    if unit_in in ["B", "b", "Back", "back"]:
        break

    unit_out = input("Unit you want to convert to: ")

    if unit_out in ["B", "b", "Back", "back"]:
        break

    value = input("Value to convert: ")

    if value in ["B", "b", "Back", "back"]:
        break

    elif isfloat(value):
        value = float(value)
        result = convert_v2(value, unit_in, unit_out)

        print(result, unit_out)

    else:
        print("You have entered a wrong value")
```

Comment: Also, if you find any other problems with my code please let me know, i try to improve myself as much as i can. Thank you

Comment: Issue with `if (unit_in and unit_out) in metric`: the statement `(unit_in and unit_out)` evaluates to `unit_out`. So, for example, if I run `('fm' and 'mm') in metric` in would evaluate to true even though `fm` is not a valid metric unit

Comment: Thank you, now i separated them to `if unit_in in metric and unit_out in metric` and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I would do is rather than use the lists of units, check if the units is equal to a string.

```py
#do this:
if unit_in == 'm' and unit_out == 'ft':
    #do the conversion here.

#instead of this:
if unit_in in ['m'] and unit_out in ['ft']
    #do the conversion here.
```

Comment: There are various reasons to use the style chosen - perhaps later they will add synonyms (m, meter), (ft,feet) and it is consistent with ```imperial``` and ```metric```

Answer (score 0):

Notes.  It is customary to mention if this is homework or a school project.  I think @G. Anderson pointed out the actual problem - your misuse/misunderstanding of 'and'.  Although python is nice that logic expressions can sound like english sentences, you do need to consider what each part of the expression does.

In the spirit of providing guidance to someone new coming to python and programming, I suggest some other things.  I don't like string constants scattered around my code.  If you mistype `'mm'` as `'mn'` in one place it can be a hard bug to spot, since the interpreter doesn't see anything wrong.  But a misspelled variable like `MN` is an error.

I also added a little validate routine, since there is also some issue that you silently allow an invalid unit to be enter like `fr` - I didn't look at what the code did in that case.

I also think you should use quotes consistently (all `'` or `"`) unless there is some reason.  Most (?) people standardize to `"` but I like `'` since it avoids the shift key... :-)

And finally, I think if you THINK about this problem a little, you will find that <s>a lot</s> *all* of your conditional logic is unneeded.  Converting from `ft` to `in` is really the same as `ft` to `cm` or `ft` to `mi`.  I think you were on the right track when you were thinking about using a dictionary. Think about what your conversion table would look like if it told you how many (units) were in a (for example) kilometer.

```
# def distance_converterv2():

# Use "constants" to prevent errors like a typo somewhere 'mn'
#  that can be hard to see.  Undefined var MN will be detected by interpreter
METRIC = KM, M, DM, CM, MM = ('km', 'm', 'dm', 'cm', 'mm')
IMPERIAL = FT, IN, MI = ('ft', 'in', 'mi')
VALID_UNITS = METRIC + IMPERIAL


def valid(unit):
    if unit not in VALID_UNITS:
        print('Invalid: ' + unit + ', must be in ' + ' '.join(VALID_UNITS))
        return False
    return True

def convert_v2(val, unit_in, unit_out):
    final = 0.0
    m = 0.0
    si = {MM: 0.001, CM: 0.01, DM: 0.1, M: 1.0, KM: 1000.0}
    if unit_in in METRIC and unit_out in METRIC:   # Per @ G. Anderson
        final = val*(si[unit_in]/si[unit_out])

    if unit_in in IMPERIAL and unit_out in IMPERIAL:   # Per @ G. Anderson
        if unit_in in [FT] and unit_out in [IN]:
            final = val * 12

        if unit_in in [IN] and unit_out in [FT]:
            final = val / 12

        if unit_in in [FT] and unit_out in [MI]:
            final = val / 5280

        if unit_in in [MI] and unit_out in [FT]:
            final = val * 5280

    if unit_in in METRIC and unit_out in IMPERIAL:
        if unit_out in [FT]:
            m = val*3.28084

        if unit_out in [IN]:
            m = val*39.37008

        if unit_out in [MI]:
            m = val/1609.34

        final = m * si[unit_in]

    if unit_in in IMPERIAL and unit_out in METRIC:
        si = {MM: 0.001, CM: 0.01, DM: 0.1, M: 1.0, KM: 1000.0}
        if unit_in in [FT]:
            m = val / 3.28084

        if unit_in in [IN]:
            m = val / 39.37008

        if unit_in in [MI]:
            m = val * 1609.34

        final = m / si[unit_out]

    return final


def isfloat(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


print('''
Welcome to Saguaro's unit converter!

First, enter the unit you want to convert from, then the unit you want to convert to
The options are: 
    mm, cm, dm, m, km
    ft, inch, mile

Whenever You want to go back press B and enter
''')

value = 0
unit_in = ''
unit_out = ''


while True:

    unit_in = input('Unit you want to convert from: ')

    if unit_in in ['B', 'b', 'Back', 'back']:
        break
    if not valid(unit_in):
        continue

    unit_out = input('Unit you want to convert to: ')

    if unit_out in ['B', 'b', 'Back', 'back']:
        break
    if not valid(unit_out):
        continue

    value = input('Value to convert: ')

    if value in ['B', 'b', 'Back', 'back']:
        break

    elif isfloat(value):
        value = float(value)
        result = convert_v2(value, unit_in, unit_out)

        print(result, unit_out)

    else:
        print('You have entered a wrong value')
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, you really help me. It's not for school, I just want to learn Python. My question is that is a long dictionary better with a lot of elements than a lot of if/elif statements?

Comment: I thought about the problem.  I think the dictionary you need will only have 8 entries and you will only need one line of code (in convert_v2).  This isn't a python problem it's mostly a "thinking about the problem" problem.  I'll update my answer with the simpler solution, maybe this weekend.  BTW, it's customary to accept/upvote the answer you find helpful.